# What is the most Pythonic way to test for match with first item of tuple in sequence of 2-tuples?

Tags: python

Suppose you have a sequence of 2-tuples:

```
seq_of_tups = (('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3))
```

and you want to test if `'a'` is the first item of any tuple in the sequence.

What is the most Pythonic way?

Convert to a dictionary and test for keys, which seems easy enough to understand? i.e.

```
'a' in dict(seq_of_tups)
```

Use a cute zip trick which is is not particularly clear unless you know the trick? i.e.

```
'a' in zip(*seq_of_tups)[0]
```

Or be really explicit with map? i.e.

```
'a' in map(lambda tup: tup[0], seq_of_tups)
```

Or is there a better way than any of these choices?

Comment: `>>> 'a' in zip(*seq_of_tups)
False` I think you mean `zip(*seq_of_tups)[0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> tups = (('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3))

>>> 'a' in (x[0] for x in tups)
True
>>> 'd' in (x[0] for x in tups)
False
```

the above solution will exit as soon as `a` is found, proof:

```
>>> tups = (('a', 1),('a',5), ('b', 2), ('c', 3))
>>> gen=(x[0] for x in tups)
>>> 'a' in gen
True
>>> list(gen)
['a', 'b', 'c']  #this result means generator stopped at first 'a'
```

Comment: Apparently Python is clever enough to not convert the generator into a list first (tested with `5 in itertools.repeat(5)`). It will work equally well as jamylak's solution.

Comment: @FelixKling: Huh, So using `in` on a generator is equivalent to using `any`. Very cool, I did not know that.

Comment: Two great answers, thanks Ashwini and jamylak, both better than any of my original choices, not least because they short-circuit the search. Seems like I'm in the minority preferring Ashwini's solution. I like it slightly better because it expresses the logic of "if this is in that list" directly, rather than inverting it to be "if any of the things in that list are this".

Comment: @JoelCornett yes, as generator generate result one-by-one, so as soon as the first `a` is found the condition becomes True and exits.

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> seq_of_tups = (('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3))
>>> any(x == 'a' for x, y in seq_of_tups)
True
```

For tuples of any size you could use this instead:

```
any(x[0] == 'a' for x in seq_of_tups)
```

Also here are some interesting timings:

```
>python -m timeit -s "seq_of_tups = (('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3))" 
                 "any(x == 'a' for x, y in seq_of_tups)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.564 usec per loop

>python -m timeit -s "seq_of_tups = (('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3))" 
                 "'a' in (x[0] for x in seq_of_tups)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.526 usec per loop

>python -m timeit -s "seq_of_tups = (('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)); 
                      from operator import itemgetter; from itertools import imap" 
                 "'a' in imap(itemgetter(0), seq_of_tups)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.343 usec per loop
```

Comment: That's a good way of avoiding traversing the whole list (on average of course).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Good point, since iteration would stop on the first item with `imap` and it's always the first item in this case. I will remove the `map` :)

Comment: +1 for `any(x[0] == 'a' for x in seq_of_tups)` as an explicit readable solution