# Removing certain letters from a string

Tags: python, string

In python, I'm supposed to write a program that asks the user for a string, and then it removes all occurrences of p, q, r, s, t (lower and upper-case), then print out everything else.
For input `Today it is Tuesday` it should print `oday i i ueday`.

I've written the code but it doesn't remove the last letter if needed.
Here is what I've written:

```
S = str(input("Please enter some text: "))
L = list(S)
for i in L :
     if i in 'tsrqpPQRST' :
         L.remove(i)
string = ""
for char in L :
     string = string + char
print(string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.translate`.

```
>>> test = 'Today it is Tuesday'
>>> removeText = 'pqrst'
>>> test.translate(None, removeText+removeText.upper())
'oday i i ueday'
```

Since you're on Python 3, use the `translate()` method like this.

```
>>> test = 'Today it is Tuesday'
>>> removeText = 'pqrst'
>>> test.translate(dict.fromkeys(ord(elem) for elem in removeText+removeText.upper()))
'oday i i ueday'
```

The problem in your code is that you're removing stuff from the list while iterating over it.

Just doing this works. (Here you make a copy, iterate over it, while removing the element from the original list)

```
>>> testList = list(test)
>>> for i in testList[:]:
        if i in 'pqrstPQRST':
            testList.remove(i)


>>> "".join(testList)
'oday i i ueday'
```

**P.S** - Instead of using `string = ''` and iterating over the list and joining the characters, just use `"".join(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression:

```
 import re
 new_string = re.sub('(?i)[pqrst]', '', S)
```

Comment: +1 - Regex solves this problem quickly and easily.  However, you can make it even better:  `re.sub('(?i)[p-t]', '', S)`.  This works because "pqrst" is in the order of the alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `join` and [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions). Combine for loop and string concatation is not efficient or pythonic. Also, string itself is iterable, no need to turn it into a list.

```
>>> s = 'Today it is Tuesday'
>>> ''.join(x for x in s if x not in 'pqrstPQRST')
'oday i i ueday'
>>>
```

Comment: [There's no advantage of using <genexp> with str.join](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/846892), it is just more readable than LC.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me a new understanding of the two. But now I should be curious about why GC in a for loop is faster.

Comment: [That depends on the data.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11964301/846892), for small/average sized loops LC are faster.

Comment: `s = ''.join([x for x in s if x not in 'pqrstPQRST'])` removes all occurrences from `s`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to do that. e.g.

```
>>> s = "helllo"
>>> s.replace("l","")
'heo'
>>> s.translate(None,"le")
'ho'
>>>
```

As a side note, you **don't have to turn a string into a list to iterate over it** but you shouldn't modify an iterable when you iterate over it, so if you would like to improve your code it would be something along the lines of:

```
>>> s
'helllo'
>>> m = ""
>>> for i in s:
        if i not in "el": #put the list of characters here
                m += i


>>> m
'ho'
>>>
```

This way you are making a copy of a string, you don't run into problems that you have when you modify it during iteration.