# Python: How do I ignore non letters in a string?

Tags: python, string, loops, character, spaces

The function prints out the individual frequency for letters in a file but I cant get it to ignore non letters, I only want it to count letters when working out the percentage frequency of each letter. This what I have so far:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as lowercase

def calcFrequencies(file):
    """Enter file name in quotations. Shows the frequency of letters in a file"""
    infile = open(file)
    text = infile.read()
    text = text.lower()

    text_length = len(text)
    counts = [0]*26

    for i in range(26):
        char=lowercase[i]
        counts[i] = 100*text.count(char)/text_length
        print("{:.1f}% of the characters are '{}'".format(counts[i],char))
    infile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `join` method with a list comprehension (faster than a genexp) to reassign the string with only the alphabetic characters before counting:

```
text = ''.join([char for char in text if char.isalpha()])
```

Comment: @Foflo just be advised, if you care about speed I believe mhlester's solution is faster.

Comment: I think he was downvoted before my answer. That said it works so the downvote is unwarranted

Comment: I was not the down voter. But you should remember, passing a generator is slower than passing a List to `str.join`. So @aj8uppal 's answer would end up to be faster than yours.

Comment: @Abhijit I actually didn't know that, could you tell me why?

Comment: @jmu303: Check this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/977038) and the Question [List comprehension vs generator expression's weird timeit results?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11964130/977038)

Answer (score 3):

Use [filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

```
>>> text = "abcd1234efg"
>>> filter(str.isalpha, text)
'abcdefg'
```

Comment: `filter` is deprecated and is best to avoid. Use List Comprehension or Loops instead

Comment: I wasn't aware. Can you share a link?

Comment: @Abhijit, I haven't found any literature to that effect. Also, in my test filter ran 43% faster than list comprehension in this case.