# Check first elements of a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list which looks like this:

```
List = [['name1','surname1'], ['name2','surname2'],['name3','surname3']]
```

I would like to check if "name1" is in the object "List". I have tried:

```
if 'name1' in List:
    print True
else:
    print False
```

and the output is 'False'. Any idea how to create a sublist (or something similar) to check the first element of every sub-list without looping through all the elements of the main list?

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

What I have thought about is:

```
for i in range(0, len(List)):
    if List[i][0] == 'name1':
        print True
```

but I want to avoid exactly this iteration with something more optimized, if possible.

Comment: Optimized in terms of speed or code length?

Comment: I'd say both, more important is speed, but also some code shortening would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Then please explain why you are using a list of lists instead of e.g. a dict.

Comment: Mmm, I'd say because I'm a newbie and still don't know very well all Python objects. I'll try to indagate the dictionaries solution, but as long as I keep on using lists maybe I better use list comprehension?

Comment: Using a list of lists is fine if the list is small (say less than 30 elements) or if performance is not critical.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this useful tip, I'll try to see how hard is to restore the code using dictionaries rather than lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a generator expression:

```
>>> 'name1' in (x[0] for x in List)
True
```

This will short-circuit as soon as `'name1'` is found and won't create any unnecessary list in memory.

Related: [List comprehension vs generator expression's weird timeit results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964130/list-comprehension-vs-generator-expressions-weird-timeit-results)

Comment: Great. I will choose this answer since it's the most optimized so far still using lists that I cannot easily change with dictionaries. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a dictionary, which seems more suitable here.

But if a list of lists is to be used, you can have such a code: `'name1' in [list[0] for list in List]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with:

```
if 'name1' in [l[0] for l in List]:
```

You can also add an `if l` at then end of the list comprehension just in case there's an empty list around:

```
if 'name1' in [l[0] for l in List if l]:  # safe if there's an empty list
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please check out my "Possible Solution" edit: isn't it this solution using the same iteration I have written? I was thinking about something a bit more optimized, if Python is offering any built-in of course :)

Comment: Ain't the same. Normally list comprehension are faster and more elegant than a for loop.

Comment: I'm new to Python, but I'd like to understand this cause it's not really clear yet to me. How can a list comprehension be faster than a "traditional" for-loop, if the iterations is doing are exactly the same (check for every value in the list if something)?

Comment: List comprehensions are done in C (in case of cpython). What this means is that the implicit `for` loop is taken care of in C, not python per se. A for loop in python create additional overhead.

Answer (score 1):

More idiomatic way to do this, is to use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function

```
>>> any('name1' == current_list[0] for current_list in my_list)
True
```

This also short circuits on the first occurrence of `name1`.

**Edit :** In case, your `name1` can be anywhere in the sub-list, you can use the `in` operator

```
>>> any('name1' in current_list for current_list in my_list)
True
```

Comment: Nice function that I didn't know, but I fear one problem. If I have: `List = [['John','Smith'], ['Andy', 'John']]`, is it gonna count two people named John while only one is actually named so?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ It will not even check the second element since the first one has the name `John`. It short-circuits :)

Comment: what about the case `List = [['Andrew','Smith'], ['Andy', 'John']]` for the name 'John'? Is the `'name1' == current_list[0]` saying to check "any" but only at the first position of every sub-list? Sorry if my questions are stupid but I'm programming in Python for not even a month :)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Thats okay. :) Please check my updated answer. `in` operator will check if the `name1` is there in the sub-list or not.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the explanation, I'll assess which solution fits better with my needs ;)