# How to see if an object of a particular type is in a Python list?

Tags: python, list, object

How do I check for a specific object type in a Python list? For example say I want to check for the `ast` module object Subscript or _ast.Subscript in a list l:

```
if Subscript in l:
    return True
```

But this has not been working. Any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Also object prints as <_ast.Subscript object at 0x7ff7f7f7f7ff>

Comment: So you want to check if `l` contains an element which is of type `_ast.Subscript`?  That's not the same as checking if the `_ast.Subscript` type is itself in the list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below:

```
#if Subscript is an instance of a type
if type(Subscript) in map(type,l):
    return True

# or if Subscript is a type such as a class
if Subscript in map(type,l):
    return True
```

Comment: Or, in one line: `return type(Subscript) in map(type,l)`

Comment: For short-circuiting you can use `itertools.imap`.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary Or Python 3 `map()`. Everyone should be writing Python 3 compatible (if not exclusive) code anyway ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
any(isinstance(x, ast.Subscript) for x in lst)
```

Timing comparisons:

```
In [20]: from itertools import imap

In [21]: lis = range(10**5) + ['a']

In [22]: %timeit any(isinstance(x, str) for x in lis)
100 loops, best of 3: 18.7 ms per loop

In [23]: %timeit str in map(type, lis)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.28 ms per loop

In [24]: %timeit str in imap(type, lis)                 #winner
100 loops, best of 3: 3.8 ms per loop


In [25]: lis = ['b'] + range(10**5) + ['a']

In [26]: %timeit any(isinstance(x, str) for x in lis)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 533 ns per loop

In [27]: %timeit str in map(type, lis)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.34 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit str in imap(type, lis)                  #winner
1000000 loops, best of 3: 227 ns per loop


In [29]: lis = range(10**3) + ['a'] + range(10**4)

In [30]: %timeit any(isinstance(x, str) for x in lis)
10000 loops, best of 3: 187 µs per loop

In [31]: %timeit str in map(type, lis)
1000 loops, best of 3: 372 µs per loop

In [32]: %timeit str in imap(type, lis)                  #winner
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.3 µs per loop
```

The difference between `imap` and `map` version is that `imap` return an iterator, so the `in` call on it will short-circuit similar to `any` and it is going to be faster than `map`([except for tiny-mid sized lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964130/list-comprehension-vs-generator-expressions-weird-timeit-results)) because `map` creates a list in memory first and then we check for the item. `any` is slow because a Python for-loop is slower than the `in` operator which operates at C-speed.

Comment: This is really better than making types of all items in a list, less overhead.

Comment: Beat me to it... this is better than the `map` solution as it will short circuit on the first matching instance.

Comment: This is better than the `map` solution as it is immediately clear what  the code is trying to accomplish... (the performance benefits are just a bonus).

Comment: @mgilson Well, that too.  ;)

Comment: I was trying to keep it close to his original code to ease understanding. But that would

Comment: Actually, for some reason, any is slower:

Comment: @Simon Why is any slower?

Comment: @Simon Are you using identical code other than `any`?  Could be something to do with `isinstance` vs `type(x) ==` if not.

Comment: @Simon It looks like you intended to add something. In any case (no pun intended), it depends on the list length and the position of the first `True`. I'm honestly a bit tired of instantly associating short circuiting with performance improvements; laziness has costs too.

Comment: @baallezx Because a Python for-loop is slower than an `in` call. Use `in` with an iterator if speed is a concern.

Comment: I can't post code in the comments. And PyFiddle is not working right now. @delman it abssolutely depends on the list length. I tried a very large list (2 million entries), with a str in the middle, int's in the rest, tested for string, and "str in map(type,l)" is faster than his any code.

Comment: Tried it with short lists (4 elements) and long ones, with over 2 million. Same result. Used the timeit function. I assume that any does not actually short circuit, but I don't really know why.

Comment: Yes it does you are correct. I still see it slower that in map... for the use case I tested. But it does depend on how you use it. in imap seems the better option IMHO.

Comment: @Simon See the examples in my timing comparisons, and you'll see when `map` is slower.

Comment: its hard to believe that the any statement with 100 loops took substantially longer per loop than the 1000000 loops.