# Remove characters with accents from string

Tags: python, unicode, duplicates

I need to deal with a corrupt database in which names are stored one time with accents and one time whithout the non-ASCII characters. In particular, I have the following two records:

```
record_1 = u'Tim Münster'  
record_2 = u'Tim Mnster'
```

Is there a possibility to find such duplicate records?

Comment: This seems trivial. You can simply remove non-ascii characters with `"".join([x for x in s if ord(x)<128])` (hacky, but works), and use set operations to check for duplicates. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @goncalopp that looks suspiciously like an answer! Why not post it as one?

Comment: @TomFenech I guess it seemed too easy to be what he was looking for

Comment: Thanks, I like this hacky solution. Will try it and eventually post an update if it did not worked completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove wrong duplicates by comparing, for example, with `re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z ]', '', record_1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove non-ascii characters with

```
def remove_nonascii(s):
    return "".join(x for x in s if ord(x)<128)
```

To check for duplicates, simply use `set`s:

```
records= set([u'Tim Mnster'])
duplicates_to_check= [u'Tim Münster']
for possible_duplicate in duplicates_to_check:
    if remove_nonascii( possible_duplicate ) in records:
        print possible_duplicate, "is a duplicate"
```

Comment: There's no need for the `[ ]` in your `join`

Comment: @TomFenech indeed, I'm still not used to using generator expressions on day-to-day situations. List comprehensions [might be slightly faster, though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964130/list-comprehension-vs-generator-expressions-weird-timeit-results)

Comment: @TomFenech Actually [`str.join` is both faster and memory-efficient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/846892) when used with a list.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary I never knew that. I might change my answer too then. Thanks!

Comment: @TomFenech If the strings are not very huge then the difference is not going to matter, and I do find `str.find` more readable when used with a <genexp>.

Answer (score 0):

Finding duplicate records-

I would do something like this:

1) remove characters with accent from the string.

```
import unicodedata

def remove_accents(input_str):
    nkfd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
    only_ascii = nkfd_form.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
    return only_ascii
```

2) check if, the string with removed accent (record_1) is equal to record_2 (by using Levenshtein distance algorithm), fuzzy match.

```
from nltk import metrics, stem, tokenize

def normalize(s):
    words = tokenize.wordpunct_tokenize(s.lower().strip())
    return ' '.join([stemmer.stem(w) for w in words])

def fuzzy_match(s1, s2, max_dist=2):
    return metrics.edit_distance(normalize(s1), normalize(s2)) <= max_dist
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ascii_letters` and `whitespace` from the `string` module:

```
import string
def ascii_or_space(s):
    return "".join(c for c in s if c in string.ascii_letters + string.whitespace)

ascii_or_space(record_1) == record_2
True
```