# How does python optimize conditional list comprehensions

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension

I read about [List comprehension without [ ] in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-in-python) so now I know that

```
''.join([str(x) for x in mylist])
```

is faster than

```
''.join(str(x) for x in mylist)
```

because "list comprehensions are highly optimized"

So I suppose that the optimization relies on the parsing of the `for` expression, sees `mylist`, computes its length, and uses it to pre-allocate the exact array size, which saves a lot of reallocation.

When using `''.join(str(x) for x in mylist)`, `join` recieves a generator blindly and has to build its list without knowing the size in advance.

But now consider this:

```
mylist = [1,2,5,6,3,4,5]
''.join([str(x) for x in mylist if x < 4])
```

How does python decide of the size of the list comprehension? Is it computed from the size of `mylist`, and downsized when iterations are done (which could be very bad if the list is big and the condition filters out 99% of the elements), or does it revert back to the "don't know the size in advance" case?

EDIT: I've done some small benchmarks and it seems to confirm that there's an optimization:

without a condition:

```
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit("''.join([str(x) for x in [1,5,6,3,5,23,334,23234]])"))
print(timeit.timeit("''.join(str(x) for x in [1,5,6,3,5,23,334,23234])"))
```

yields (as expected):

```
3.11010817019474
3.3457350077491026
```

with a condition:

```
print(timeit.timeit("''.join([str(x) for x in [1,5,6,3,5,23,334,23234] if x < 50])"))
print(timeit.timeit("''.join(str(x) for x in [1,5,6,3,5,23,334,23234] if x < 50)"))
```

yields:

```
2.7942209702566965
3.0316467566203276
```

so conditional listcomp still is faster.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [List comprehension vs generator expression's weird timeit results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964130/list-comprehension-vs-generator-expressions-weird-timeit-results)

Comment: not bad, but in this question there's never a condition _after_ the for loop. Only in the expression itself, which means that the size is known in advance.

Comment: I think the behavior on how Python deals with `for x in xx for y in yy` in the usage of linked question and `for x in y if x<123` in your question should be similar as in both the case Python do not know the size of resultant list until the expression is evaluated. *(just the logical assumption, not sure if that is True)*

Comment: I suggest you to look at the source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/join.h

Comment: @Kasramvd I'm aware that `join` creates a list if it's not already one, to know the size. The question was about list comprehension size computation when there's a condition. Now I'm beginning to believe that the worst-case size is allocated, and the list is downsized afterwards.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I've understood your question. If you rally delve into the source you'll realize the you need to seek `PyBytes_GET_SIZE` and then you might find your answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

List comprehensions *don't* pre-size the list, even when they totally could. You're assuming the presence of an optimization that isn't actually done.

The list comprehension is faster because all the iterator machinery and the work of entering and exiting the genexp stack frame has a cost. The list comprehension doesn't need to pay that cost.

Comment: Could there be a substantial gain, then, in preallocating the list? As @Jean-François noted, this "could be bad if the list is big and the condition filters out 99% of the elements", but then again, it could be *good* if the condition filtered out only 1% of the elements!

Comment: @RadLexus exactly: if the collection iterated upon is a `list` or something with a known-in-advance size and no condition, no double "for" loop, it could be a special case (very common) to pre-allocate the list size. Would be applicable 80% of the time in the existing codes!