# Printing generator objects in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I created my own iterator (to learn how they work) as follows

```
class Reverse():
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
        self.index = len(word)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        self.index -=1
        if self.index < 0:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.word[self.index]

print (char for char in Reverse("word"),end="")
```

I know I can say:

```
rev = Reverse("word")
for char in rev:
    print(char, end="")
```

but I was hoping to be able to do it in a single line

```
print (char for char in Reverse("word"),end="")
```

This doesn't work and raises an error. If I remove the `end=""` it prints out a `generator object`. Surely by including a `for loop` in the `print` statement it should iterate through my generator object and print each item? 
Why does this not happen

Answer (score 2):

A generator is a lazy iterator. When you use a for loop, you are manually exhausting the generator. When you print it out in a single line, you are not exhausting it by iterating.

You can unpack the generator to exhaust it and get all of the values:

```
print(*(char for char in Reverse('word')), sep='')
```

I’ve changed `end` for `sep` as you are doing everything in 1 print call so want to separate each ‘argument’ (character) with no space.

You can also do the following:

```
print(*Reverse('word'), sep='')
```

As `Reverse` is already an iterator, you are able to exhaust it.

Answer (score 1):

> Surely by including a for loop in the `print` statement it should iterate through my generator object and print each item?

No, it will print the string representation of a generator object.

If you want to output *what this object generates*, you can use a starred expression:

```
print(*(char for char in Reverse("word")),end="")
```

This is because the `for` loop in a generator expression isn't actually executed at the instantiation of the generator object, and that's the whole point of generators: you can have an infinite generator and still be able to pass it around as a regular value and consume finite chunks of it, all that without having infinite amounts of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Why not like this?

`print(''.join([char for char in Reverse("word")]))`

Comment: The `[ ]` create an unnecessary list, and you also do not have to iterate manually. Just do `print(''.join(Reverse("word")))`

Comment: @DeepSpace it's faster to join the list comprehension than a genex. I need to dig the reference out, but the genex will be expanded before `join` can work

Comment: @DeepSpace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519707/how-does-python-optimize-conditional-list-comprehensions

Comment: @roganjosh It sounds a bit weird but I'll wait for the reference. Anyway, for longer "words" I'm pretty sure the overhead of the list comp will be more noticeable.

Comment: @DeepSpace more-specifically, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/4799172) but I guess you've probably already followed the rabbit hole and found that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
x = my_objects.objects.all() # x, turns to a QuerySet

for i in range(len(x)):
    print(x[i])
```