# replacing chars in a string in one-liner

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was a given a string `s = "1_2_3_4"` and I wanted to replace all `"_"` with another char - `"0"`.

I used `s = ''.join([c for c in s if c != '_'])` to eliminate the `"_"` from my string, but I don't know how to replace the values. I wanted to do something like `s = ''.join([c for c in s if c != '_' else '0'])` but of course, that's invalid syntax.

I'm well aware that `s.replace('_','0')` will be a much better option, but I'm just trying to understand how can I use if statements inside a list comprehension. This will serve me for other cases when the class I'm using will not have `replace` method.

Comment: Maybe `s = ' '.join([c if c != '_' else '0' for c in s])` ?

Comment: in before "just use `s.replace('_','0')`"

Comment: @TomWyllie Yes, it is more pythonic, but the OP is wanting to do it by list comprehension

Comment: @mangoHero1 yes I know - I was making a joke about the inevitable comments telling him to use `str.replace` even though he explicitly asked for a one-liner.

Comment: @TomWyllie Ah right lol. I'm hoping no one would really be ignorant of that detail :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
s = ''.join([c if c != '_' else '0' for c in s])
```

Btw another option would be:

```
s = '0'.join(s.split('_'))
```

I do not fully understand why not `s.replace('_', '0')` though.

---

> **Now as far as the *"why"* is concerned:**
>
> This is simply how the syntax of the language is. When the `if` comes
>   before the `for` an `else` is also expected (an error is thrown if
>   there isn't one). When the `if` comes after the `for`, an `else`
>   following it **is not allowed**.

Comment: Beat me to it by twelve seconds... ;)

Comment: Why the else is legal before the loop but not after? And for the not using replace, I just want to understand better the if statements inside a list

Comment: @CIsForCookies , The left value is the appended value in each iteration, each iteration the left value is appended to the result list. If you do the if condition on the right, you will skip iterations that don't satisfy the if condition so you won't be able to modify the returned value. Therefore the if condition should be on the left side, as you do want to modify the returned value according to the value in each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Try this generator expression with an in-line `if` `else` statement;

```
s = "1_2_3_4"
s = ''.join(((char if char != '_' else '0') for char in s))
print(s)
```

It's not a list comprehension, which is better in this use case. Still a one liner but is more efficient on larger strings.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but generator efficiency here (in a 8 chars string) is nothing notable, isn't it? I find list easier to use, and more intuitive when I don't need to think of execution speed

Comment: @CIsForCookies Actually with the use of `join` `list`s are faster than `generators`. For this difference to be notable, bigger strings are needed though.

Comment: "is nothing notable" - you are completely correct, the performance enhancement is trivial. Probably not even measurable on this. I just think it's a good habit to get into. :)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis is it because join expects list or tuple and if generator is provided it will has to create a list and only then use join?

Comment: @TomWyllie, ClsForCookies [See this comparison for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964130/list-comprehension-vs-generator-expressions-weird-timeit-results)

Comment: Actually @Ev.Kounis they possibly are, you make a valid point. I don't really know about the relative speeds. Generators are certainly far more memory efficient though.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (it's better to use replace but you wished to use the join on a list):

```
s = "1_2_3_4"

s = ''.join([c if c != '_' else '0'  for c in s])

print (s)
>>> '1020304'
```