# Why does a list comprehension take longer to execute than using += in for loop?

Tags: python

Taking this code, for example, can you explain why using a list comprehension when adding sum of integers in list took longer than using a normal `for` loop?

```
class Store:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.items = []

    def add_items(self, name, price):
        self.items.append({'name':name, 'price': price})

    def stock_price(self):
        return sum([item['price'] for item in self.items])

    def stock_price2(self):
        total = 0
        for item in self.items:
            total += item.get('price')
        return total

store = Store("Jay")
store.add_items("nike", 100)
store.add_items('puma', 200)
print(timeit.Timer(lambda: store.stock_price()).timeit(number=1000))
print(timeit.Timer(lambda: store.stock_price2()).timeit(number=1000))
```

result of stock_price:     0.0007737720006844029

result of stock_price2:    0.0006722800026182085

Comment: The list comprehension version builds a new list then invokes a function call; if you don't actually *need* the new list, it seems inevitable that a simpler loop will be faster.

Comment: Try that but with a list which doesn't have just one item (but say a thousand items) and post the results. I bet the list comprehension will be faster

Comment: Thanks to @jonrsharpe: the approach with summing the generator is not really faster than list comprehension. The explanation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11964478/747744 (TLDR: generators can be slow because of extra calls to ```next()```)

Answer (score 1):

In the first function, there is an extra step. It first creates a list, then sums it all together with `sum`. The second function simply iterates over them and adds it to a total.

Comment: In fact the extra step in first function doesn't make it slower: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11964478/747744 (I've rechecked it on 10 million items)

Answer (score 0):

As jonrsharpe suggested, list comrehension makes a **copy** of the list.
So what `stock_price()` does is actually make a copy of the list, and only then iterating on it and calculating the sum. (note that the builtin `sum` function is actually more efficient than a `for` look, as it is implemented in C)

On the other hand, `stock_price2()` does not copy the list, which saves a lot of time spent on allocations for the new list.