# String operation performs incorrectly

Tags: python, python-3.x

In `main.py` i have this

```
import RemoveShortWords as rs

procLine="the   in  shear flow past a flat plate"
procLine = rs.RemomeOneTwoCharWords(procLine)
print(procLine)
```

and `RemoveShortWords.py` is this

```
def RemomeOneTwoCharWords(procLine):

    procLine = str(procLine)

    for word in procLine.split():

        if(len(word)<=2):
            procLine = procLine.replace(word,"")


    return procLine
```

print returns this

> the     sher flow pst  flt plte

as you can see function removes words with less than 2 characters.
But, for some reason, it removed all "a" characters too. For Example, "flat" became "flt"

Why?

Comment: @PM2Ring, sometimes people may miss things. Why not just try to help to explain what's wrong, instead of posting useless comment?

Comment: @PM2Ring , it is not duplicate, i'm not asking how to remove 2 char words, I  asked why code performed not as intended

Comment: Reopening. The question is about why the code fails; the dupe target did not contain an answer to that question. It may be related, but it's not a dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable `procLine` has `the   in  shear flow past a flat plate`

And `procLine.split()`
['the', 'in', 'shear', 'flow', 'past', 'a', 'flat', 'plate']

In `for` loop, it finds `a` and replaces `a` in `procLine` with empty or removes the character. **Note**: it would do same if some word was with `in` e.g. `string` to `strg`.

Instead I would suggest something like `list comprehension` may work:

```
procLine = ' '.join([w for w in procLine.split() if len(w)>2])
```

Comment: oh yes. I missed that somehow. Thank you

Comment: `Happy Coding`.

Comment: Why not a generator then?

Comment: @U9-Forward There are discussions on comparison of list comprehension and generator comprehension https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964130/list-comprehension-vs-generator-expressions-weird-timeit-results

Comment: @student Okay yeah that's right it's slower, but less memory taken, and two less characters to type, haha

Comment: @U9-Forward For specific case with `.join` the answer mentions `list comprehension` is better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/5916727

Comment: @student Yeah that's true

Answer (score 3):

`replace` replaces **all** occurrences.

> str.replace(old, new[, count])
>
> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq)

So once the word "a" is reached in the input, `procLine.replace("a", "")` will remove all "a"s in the entire string. If you only want to replace words shorter than 2 characters, you could use for example list-comprehension:

```
return ' '.join([s for s in procLine.split(' ') if len(s) > 2])
```

Comment: @PM2Ring Interesting; I didn't know that one. Thanks for the info :) I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

One thing i think is confusing you is procLine.split() doesn't actually modify procLine.

```
def RemomeOneTwoCharWords(procLine):
    procLine = str(procLine)
    temp = ""
    for word in procLine.split():
        if len(word)>=2:
            temp += word + " "
    return(temp)
 
procLine="the   in  shear flow past a flat plate"
procLine = RemomeOneTwoCharWords(procLine)
print(procLine)
```

gives

```
the shear flow past flat plate
```