# Why is summing list comprehension faster than generator expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Not sure if title is correct terminology.

If you have to compare the characters in 2 strings (A,B) and count the number of matches of  chars in B against A:

```py
sum([ch in A for ch in B])
```

is faster on %timeit than

```py
sum(ch in A for ch in B)
```

I understand that the first one will create a list of bool, and then sum the values of 1.
The second one is a generator. I'm not clear on what it is doing internally and why it is slower?

Thanks.

Edit with %timeit results:

**10 characters**

generator expression

list

10000 loops, best of 3: 112 µs per loop

10000 loops, best of 3: 94.6 µs per loop

**1000 characters**

generator expression

list

100 loops, best of 3: 8.5 ms per loop

100 loops, best of 3: 6.9 ms per loop

**10,000 characters**

generator expression

list

10 loops, best of 3: 87.5 ms per loop

10 loops, best of 3: 76.1 ms per loop

**100,000 characters**

generator expression

list

1 loop, best of 3: 908 ms per loop

1 loop, best of 3: 840 ms per loop

Comment: How long are the strings? Generators are data-lazy, it's possible this adds some overhead that for short strings will be greater than what you save by not copying the data.

Comment: Because python is very, very good at creating lists.

Comment: Hmm even with strings of length 10000000, the list version is faster than the generator version... I'm also curious about the speed difference.

Comment: Asymptotically, they appear to be converging. Eventually, the cost of having to do two traversals and build the list may outweigh the more expensive generator traversal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I took a look at the disassembly of each construct (using [dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html)). I did this by declaring these two functions:

```
def list_comprehension():
    return sum([ch in A for ch in B])

def generation_expression():
    return sum(ch in A for ch in B)
```

and then calling `dis.dis` with each function.

For the list comprehension:

```
 0 BUILD_LIST               0
 2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
 4 FOR_ITER                12 (to 18)
 6 STORE_FAST               1 (ch)
 8 LOAD_FAST                1 (ch)
10 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (A)
12 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
14 LIST_APPEND              2
16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
18 RETURN_VALUE
```

and for the generator expression:

```
 0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
 2 FOR_ITER                14 (to 18)
 4 STORE_FAST               1 (ch)
 6 LOAD_FAST                1 (ch)
 8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (A)
10 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
12 YIELD_VALUE
14 POP_TOP
16 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2
18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
20 RETURN_VALUE
```

The disassembly for the actual summation is:

```
 0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sum)
 2 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x7f49dc395240, file "/home/mishac/dev/python/kintsugi/KintsugiModels/automated_tests/a.py", line 12>)
 4 LOAD_CONST               2 ('generation_expression.<locals>.<genexpr>')
 6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
 8 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (B)
10 GET_ITER
12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
16 RETURN_VALUE
```

but this `sum` disassembly was constant between both your examples, with the only difference being the loading of `generation_expression.<locals>.<genexpr>` vs `list_comprehension.<locals>.<listcomp>` (so just loading a different local variable).

The differing bytecode instructions between the first two disassemblies are `LIST_APPEND` for the list comprehension vs. the conjunction of `YIELD_VALUE` and `POP_TOP` for the generator expression.

I won't pretend I know the intrinsics of Python bytecode, but what I gather from this is that the generator expression is implemented as a queue, where the value is generated and then popped. This popping doesn't have to happen in a list comprehension, leading me to believe there'll be a slight amount of overhead in using generators.

Now this doesn't mean that generators are always going to be slower. Generators excel at being memory-efficient, so there will be a threshold N such that list comprehensions will perform slightly better before this threshold (because memory use won't be a problem), but after this threshold, generators will *significantly* perform better.

Comment: Can you please show the code you used to get the bytecode instructions? I tried as well but got different instructions.

Comment: @jakub Yup, added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I got the same results now. Great answer

Comment: Also, `sum` is written in C and uses the list iterator's `tp_next` function which doesn't have to go through the yield/pop op codes for each value. I think the extra overhead is in YIELD.

Comment: Does the generator produce something that is then summed, the way the list comprehension produces a list of bools?

Comment: Generators are not implemented as queues.

Answer (score 1):

Generators are usually slower than list comprehension, the whole point of generators is to be memory efficient because they yield each item by creating them in a lazy fashion (only when actually needed). They favor memory efficency over speed.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what that means in this context. The sum(list comprehension) first produces a list of bool, and then sums the 1's. What is the generator expression doing differently?

Comment: In my understanding of generators they require multiple next calls which can (but not always) makes them slower, see here: The generator uses next calls as u can see here:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#the-details So longer iterables like strings lead to more next calls which slows down.

Comment: I found a SO answer explaining it in more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964130/list-comprehension-vs-generator-expressions-weird-timeit-results